# Why do i get "useless cast" when casting MutableLiveData to LiveData?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata

I have an array of feedback channels because (outside of question scope) in my `ViewModel`.

Now, I don't want to expose my `MutableLiveData` to outside my `Viewmodel`.

So, i make a private list of `LiveData` objects, but compiler complains of "Useless Cast"

```
private val _feedbackChannels = Array(10) { MutableLiveData<FeedbackEvent>() }
val feedbackChannels
    get() = _feedbackChannels.map{
        @Suppress("USELESS_CAST") // it is not useless as it no longer exposes the mutableLiveData
        it as LiveData<*>
    }
```

Why do I get `USELESS_CAST` warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler doesn't realize you're doing it only to force implication of property type.

Just specify type explicitly and you'll be able to drop the cast entirely. You won't even have to use map, a simple `toList()` will do:

```
private val _feedbackChannels = Array(10) { MutableLiveData<FeedbackEvent>() }
val feedbackChannels : List<LiveData<FeedbackEvent>>
    get() = _feedbackChannels.toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the compiler doesn't understand the point of the cast. In order to do this in a more explicit way and remove the costly `map` function, you can just upcast it like this:

```
private val _feedbackChannels = Array(10) { MutableLiveData<FeedbackEvent>() }
val feedbackChannels: Array<out LiveData<FeedbackEvent>>
    get() = _feedbackChannels
```

**Edit**

If you wanted to expose a `List` specifically (avoid exposing a mutable array) then you should probably just create one in the first place:

```
private val _feedbackChannels = List(10) { MutableLiveData<FeedbackEvent>() }
val feedbackChannels: List<out LiveData<FeedbackEvent>>
    get() = _feedbackChannels
```

Comment: Thanks, marked the other one as correct because this still  exposes (mutable) Array but it did answer my question :)

Comment: Updated my answer just to clarify an alternative to the accepted answer!